# How do I save the data on a user control before switching to a different one?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF Application with different user controls. Each of them can be accessed by clicking a button on the left side. My issue is, when I am in one of the user controls and filling out the data in textboxes, combo boxes etc, I may have to stop it mid way and click on another user control. While doing that, I need to keep the data in the previous user control intact so that when I return to the first user control, the data should be present in all the controls before I left it. How do I achieve this?  Here's a sample picture of how my application looks like:

[image]

Picture Credit: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

From the picture, if I am in the Products Page, I might have several text boxes with data entered in there. For a variety of reasons, I may have to step away from this and click on Home Page or some other page , do some work there and return back to the Products page. When I return, I need the data to be present as is when I left it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Data should available in the ViewModel object. Show your code if data not available.

Comment: This is too broad as it stands. Typically you'd have a ViewModel behind you form and that should be saving changes back to your Model. If that makes no sense to you whatsoever, then you should probably start with some tutorials on MVVM and WPF.

Comment: Why dont you simply use a tabcontrol to achive this? This way you do not have to create ne controls/objects or instances of you viewmodel?

Comment: What you probaly do is on a button click you create a new usercontrol ‚new MyControl()‘ and show it in the container but you need to keep the instance of that control and redisplay it if you click on the same butten again. However as stated before a tabcontrol does exactly that for you

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. I did not think about it properly before posting the question. I do see the data is present in the View Model. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DenisSchaf What you are suggesting is a very bad idea. OP should be creating controls via data templating. He is working with a decent tutorial which will show him the right way to do MVVM with WPF. Tab controls have nothing to do with this. If he has the templating done right, he can keep the same viewmodel instance and display it, or not, wherever or whenever he likes, in a tab control, a contentcontrol, a menu item, a listbox item -- anything.

Comment: please elaborate. Where is the adventage of creating his own functions to display multible tabs with different usercontrols when there is a tabcontrol that has been tested over and over again and works reliable. A Tab control does not break with MVVM whatsoever as far as i am aware

Comment: @DenisSchaf This is an MVVM question. You should not recommend creating controls with the `new` operator, or worry about "keeping an instance of the control", because that's a very bad way to do MVVM.

Comment: But he obviously creates a new object otherwise his control would keep its data bound thats why i saied he will need to keep that object in memory. Is that correct mvvm to start woth? No! But does it resolve his issue? Yes. Did i recommend a mvvm compliable solution by using a tabcontrol? Yes

Comment: @DenisSchaf The data is in the viewmodel. If he has the viewmodel, he has the data. The control is irrelevant: When you want to show the data to the user, bind it somewhere, and let the datatemplate display it. When the binding changes, the control goes away and it won't be missed. This is basic MVVM stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have create a ViewModel to each diferent user control.
ViewModel remains in memory until you process that or make a diferent process.
For Example you hava a User control for your Main Page, that's mean you have a view (MainPageView) of your user control for your main page, that view belong to a ViewModelMainPage. 
For Products you maybe have a ProductView, that's belong to ViewModelProducts.
You must create a ManagerViewModel to manage the view for diferents user control.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. I did not think about it properly before posting the question. I do see the data is present in the View Model. Thanks for the help!